# SpringBoot MongoDB inserting into test database

Tags: java, mongodb, rest, spring-boot

I have a simple SpringBoot Application which does the CRUD operations using mongodb
i have used the following application.properties :-

```
spring.data.mogodb.host=localhost
spring.data.mogodb.port=27017
spring.data.mogodb.database=EmulationDb
```

ideally it should insert the documents in EmulationDb, but it is inserting in the test db, can any one suggest what went wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this property and see if it works:

`spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://localhost:27017/EmulationDb`

## edit

just noticed you have a typo in your properties:
`mogodb` instead of `mongodb` (missing `n`)

Comment: is it mandetory to give the URI, beacause in one of my project it is working without these property